# ToolStripMenuItem Background Image disappears on Mouse Over (.net winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've set a BackgroundImage on my ToolStripMenuItem that is part of a ContextMenuItem.

When I mouse over it, the background image disappears.  The blue "highlight" box shows up over it (at least I think that's what's happening).

How can I display a background image when the mouse is over it?

I tried setting the image in an MouseEnter event but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you need to use a custom renderer.

#### Set Renderer on the ContextMenuStrip

```
contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new BackgroundImageRenderer();
```

#### Add this "Renderer Class"

Customize the variables as appropriate.

```
private class BackgroundImageRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Item.Selected)
        {
            base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Item.Name == "theNameOfMyToolStripMenuItem")
            {
                Image backgroundImage = global::YourProject.Properties.Resources.ImageFileName;
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, e.Item.Width, e.Item.Height);
            }
            else {
                base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a class deriving from ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

```
public class customRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            // check if the object being rendered is actually a ToolStripButton
            if (e.Item is ToolStripButton)
            {
                ToolStripButton button = e.Item as ToolStripButton;

                // only render checked items differently
                if (button.Checked || button.Selected)
                {
                   //do work here
                }
                else
                    base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
            }
            // if this object is not a ToolStripButton, use the normal render event
            else
                base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
        }

        protected override void OnRenderItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            //do checking here like above
            base.OnRenderItemBackground(e);
        }

    }
```

set the renderes of controls you have on form constructor  - works for all from toolstrip(toolstrippbackground,toolstripbutton,contexmenustrip,etc)
i just overrided OnRenderButtonBackground because you mention this,you can override other methods of ToolStripProfessionalRenderer

```
toolStrip1.Renderer = new customRenderer();//if you have this and want to override any behaviour
            menuStrip1.Renderer = new customRenderer();//if you have this and want to override any behaviour
            contextMenuStrip1.Renderer = new customRenderer();//if you have this and want to override any behaviour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class customRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderButtonBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if the object being rendered is actually a ToolStripButton
        if (e.Item is ToolStripButton)
        {
            ToolStripButton button = e.Item as ToolStripButton;

            // only render checked items differently
            if (button.Checked || button.Selected)
            {
               //do work here
            }
            else
                base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
        }
        // if this object is not a ToolStripButton, use the normal render event
        else
            base.OnRenderButtonBackground(e);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //do checking here like above
        base.OnRenderItemBackground(e);
    }

}
```

this worked for me